# How to use regexp in where clause to filter rows in Postgres?

Tags: sql, regex, postgresql, select, where-clause

I have following table in postgres 11.0

| col1 | col2 | col3 | col4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| NCT00001723 | 4894402 | xenical (orlistat)capsules | xenical |
| NCT00001724 | 4894403 | xenical (orlistat)capsules | orlistat |
| NCT00001725 | 4894404 | capsules | capsules |
| NCT00001726 | 4894405 | insulin | ins |

I would like filter above rows such that either col3 = col4 or col3 exact content should be contained in col4.

The desired output is:

| col1 | col2 | col3 | col4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| NCT00001723 | 4894402 | xenical (orlistat)capsules | xenical |
| NCT00001724 | 4894403 | xenical (orlistat)capsules | orlistat |
| NCT00001725 | 4894404 | capsules | capsules |

I am trying below query to get this output.

```sql
SELECT
    *
FROM
    table 
where col3 = col4 or                         --exact match
regexp_matches(col3, '(.*).*\(') = col4 or   --match content before brackets
regexp_matches(col3, '.*\(.*\).*') = col4 --match content in brackets
```

Any suggestions here will be really helpful. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I followed you correctly, you could just use [word boundaries escape `\y`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-matching.html#POSIX-ESCAPE-SEQUENCES):

> `\y`:     matches only at the beginning or end of a word

In your query:

```
select * from mytable where col3 ~  ('\y' || col4 || '\y')
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=dad2b63ce3fdef51bc2e3736e81c4b00)**:

| col1 | col2 | col3 | col4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| NCT00001723 | 4894402 | xenical (orlistat)capsules | xenical |
| NCT00001724 | 4894403 | xenical (orlistat)capsules | orlistat |
| NCT00001725 | 4894404 | capsules | capsules |

Comment: Whenever I am using that I get this error '[Code: 0, SQL State: 2201B]  ERROR: invalid regular expression: quantifier operand invalid' What does that mean?

Comment: @rshar  It means your col4 contains some values (not the ones you show) which have characters which are meaningful to the regexp engine.